# EXCEL 2013 if/and function assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to write a function that if C3=C2 and H:H=1 then return the value for G:G, can anyone assist with this?

Comment: Return into what, a full column of values? One cell? If one cell, do you want the sum? A concatenated list?  A mock up of the data and expected outcome would help us help you.

Comment: H:H and G:G specify a range of cells.  What did you intend H:H=1 to mean: every cell in column H is 1, the sum of all cells in H is 1, etc?

Comment: @Steven I think he/she means count all H:H as a sum and check if its equal to 1 and then return total of G:G.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Lori. Please give us some more information about how your data is arranged, and in what format, so we can try to help you. [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/)  has a great tool to make text tables for posting here. Or you can link to a screenshot from an image share site.

Comment: by H:H=1....the values in H are 1 and 2

Comment: I want to return the value that is in G if the value in H=1 and the value in C2=C1

Comment: @Lori from all of the H cells? So all cells that start with H counted together? And the same for G cells? Because in that case my answer is valid. And why are you using C2=C1 now instead of C3=C2? I mean you can still change my formula to make this work.

Comment: @RamonRobben no your answer is not valid.  Lori stated that H will have either 1 or 2 and that the return should be G where H is one, not the sum of H.

Comment: @Lori where do you want the return?  Please mock data and expected return.

Comment: @ScottCraner in that case SUM(H:H) can be changed to the cell name. Same goes for SUM(G:G)

Comment: @ScottCraner you are correct, you get what I am asking!!!

Answer (score 2):

The formula you want is:

```
=IF(AND($C$1=$C$2,H2=1),G2,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer I didn't even think about using AND. Oh well another thing learned.

Comment: @Lori please mark as correct  by clicking the check mark by the answer